# Why FindNextFile is not working in my C# code?

Tags: c#, windows

The code is not working for me. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5. I am not getting file name. The return value from FindNextFile is null. The reason not to use Directory.GetFiles() is that i want to traverse file one by one. For Directory.GetFiles(), i am gettign all the files in array at a time

```
struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    public uint dwReserved0;
    public uint dwReserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string cAlternateFileName;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("dir.txt", false);
        string dir = Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd = new WIN32_FIND_DATA();
        IntPtr h = FindFirstFile((dir + @"\*.*"), out wfd);
        while (FindNextFile(h, out wfd))
            sw.WriteLine(wfd.cFileName);
        FindClose(h);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend updating to a supported version of the .NET Framework (and a more recent version of Visual Studio), at which point you can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. Continuing to use an unsupported version of .NET leaves you open to unpatched security issues etc.

Comment: You didn't mark your structure as having sequential layout. That's one problem, it may not be the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Many Windows APIs support two string types: ANSI (8-bit characters) and Wide (16-bit characters). The problem here seems to be that you are calling the wide version of the APIs but interpreting the results as ANSI.

You can fix this by marking the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` struct as unicode (or auto). `CharSet.Auto` and `CharSet.Unicode` seem to do the same thing here.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    struct WIN32_FIND_DATA {
```

**UPDATE**

Try adding an `[Out]` attribute to the imports as suggested by Hans Passant.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, [Out] out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile, [Out] out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
```

Comment: i have tried this. but issue is not solved. I am getting value of **wfd.cFileName** as .(dot) always

Comment: @Sanjog - I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. I tried this with VS2010 (the oldest version of VS that I have available) and .NET 3.5 and it worked perfectly. This seems like a different problem. `FindFirstFile` is probably returning the `.`. It seems like `FindNextFile` is not overwriting `wfd` for some reason.

Comment: The WIN32_FIND_DATA parameter requires the [Out] attribute, necessary to tell the pinvoke marshaler to copy back the struct after the call.